# Scroll programmatically collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll, uicollectionview

I have a horizontally collection view .
What I want is to add a button, and when is pressed to auto scroll to the next cells. How to do this?

I was trying this method but it's not working:

```
- (IBAction)scrollCollection:(id)sender {

    NSIndexPath *newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

    NSArray *indexPaths = [self.notesCollection indexPathsForSelectedItems];
    if ( indexPaths.count > 0 )
    {
        NSIndexPath *oldIndexPath = indexPaths[0];
        NSInteger oldRow = oldIndexPath.row;
        newIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:oldRow + 1 inSection:oldIndexPath.section];
    }
}
```

and this:

```
- (IBAction)scrollCollection:(id)sender {

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout *)[self.notesCollection collectionViewLayout];
    [self.notesCollection setPagingEnabled:YES];
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
     self.notesCollection.contentOffset = self.scrollingPoint;
    // Here you have to respond to user interactions or else the scrolling will not stop until it reaches the endPoint.
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(self.scrollingPoint, self.endPoint)) {
        [self.scrollingTimer invalidate];
    }
    // Going one pixel to the right.
    self.scrollingPoint = CGPointMake(self.scrollingPoint.x, self.scrollingPoint.y+1);
}
```

Comment: [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath: newIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint scrollingPoint, endPoint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *scrollingTimer;
@synthesize scrollingPoint, endPoint;
@synthesize scrollingTimer;

- (void)scrollSlowly {
    // Set the point where the scrolling stops.
    self.endPoint = CGPointMake(0, 300);
    // Assuming that you are starting at {0, 0} and scrolling along the x-axis.
    self.scrollingPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    // Change the timer interval for speed regulation. 
    self.scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.015 target:self selector:@selector(scrollSlowlyToPoint) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (void)scrollSlowlyToPoint {
    self.collectionView.contentOffset = self.scrollingPoint;
    // Here you have to respond to user interactions or else the scrolling will not stop until it reaches the endPoint.
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(self.scrollingPoint, self.endPoint)) {
        [self.scrollingTimer invalidate];
    }
    // Going one pixel to the right.
    self.scrollingPoint = CGPointMake(self.scrollingPoint.x, self.scrollingPoint.y+1);
}
```

Or you can use this code too.

```
NSInteger section = [self numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:collectionView] - 1;
NSInteger item = [self collectionView:collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] - 1;
NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:item inSection:section];
[collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Comment: this is making vertically scroll . What about horizontally ?

Comment: Set UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal

Comment: [yourCollectionView setPagingEnabled:YES];